# Why does casting an array of charcters return a long number instead of ASCII value?

Tags: c

I am trying to cast an array of characters to `int` (or the corresponding ASCII value), when I try to convert a single `char` to `int` works fine but when I try to do it with an array it doesn't quite work.

Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

This is an example of a single `char` to `int`:

```
char inputCharacter;
int ASCIIValue;

scanf("%c", &inputCharacter);

ASCIIValue = (int) inputCharacter;
printf("%i", ASCIIValue);
```

Input: a

Output: 97

This is an example of a `char` array to `int`:

```
char inputCharacter[10]
int ASCIIValue;

scanf("%c", &inputCharacter);

ASCIIValue = (int) inputCharacter;
printf("%i", ASCIIValue);
```

Input: a

Output: 5896032

Expected Output: 97

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you convert an array of multiple characters into a *single* numeric value?

Comment: `ASCIIValue = inputCharacter[0]` will get you the expected value for the following `printf` call.

Comment: name of the array is a pointer to the array, which has the same value as pointer to the first element of the array, so here the base address of `inputCharacter` is being casted to int and hence the behaviour.

Comment: @RinkeshP: The name of an array is not a pointer to the array. In many contexts, an array is converted to a pointer to the first element of the array (which is different from a pointer to the array), but this does not occur in all contexts, and students should learn the correct rules and not be taught that the name of an array is a pointer to the array.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes you are right. I should have framed it better.

Comment: Matteo, Curious: given "Why does casting an array of charcters return a long instead of ASCII value?", why did you think `(int) inputCharacter` returned a `long` and not an `int`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It was supposed to be long number, not long. I will edit it now!

Comment: @Matteo To improve clarity, if you do not mean the type `long`, consider some word other than _long_.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it was a typo unfortunately. I have fixed it.

Comment: Given all the answers in the posts seems that what I did was print out the address to the pointer of the first element. Said so what would be the best approach to convert a char array to an int array? With a loop iterating through every item in the array?

Comment: @Matteo Read my answer again

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are printing the base address (`&`) of the first element of `inputCharacter`, which is the 0<sup>th</sup> element.

The address of a variable is of type `size_t`, but you are using `"%i"` format specifier in `printf()`. Correct format specifier to addresses is `"%p"`.

To get ASCII value, you need to de-reference it like:

```c
int ASCII_0 = (int)inputCharacter[0];
.
.
.
int ASCII_9 = (int)inputCharacter[9];
```

Or, better *use a loop*.

*Converting char array to int array*:

```c
int ASCII_vals[10] = {};
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(inputCharacter)/sizeof(inputCharacter[0]); i++)
{
    ASCII_vals[i] = inputCharacter[i];
}
```

Edit:

You can get the size of `inputCharacter`, using `sizeof()` operator.

```c
int len = sizeof(inputCharacter) / sizeof(inputCharacter[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

With `char inputCharacter[10]`, `inputCharacter` is an *array*.

When an array is used, as in `(int) inputCharacter`, the array is converted to the address of the first element<sup>*1</sup>.  It is like `(int) &inputCharacter[0]`.  That address, which may be wider than an `int`, is converted to an `int`, not a `long` as in the question.  In OP's case, that result was 5896032.  The address has nothing to do with the content of the array.  Expecting 97 is not supported.

---

Tip: save time and enable all warnings....

```
char inputCharacter[10];
scanf("%c", &inputCharacter);
```

... may generate a warning like

```
warning: format '%c' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[10]' [-Wformat=]
```

This hints the something is amiss.

---

<sup>*1</sup>

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type “array of type” is converted to an expression with type “pointer to type” that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.  C17dr § 6.3.2.1 3